# How to modify SDK manager path?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-import

[image]

```
 "Error:Cause: failed to find target with hash string 'android-19' in:
 E:\android\android_sdk"
```

but I have modified SDK path as `"E:\android\android_sdk_19\Android\Android\sdk"`,which is shown in the pic below.
I changed Project structure-SDK Location as `"E:\android\android_sdk_19\Android\Android\sdk"` too.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error hints that you don't have the SDK for Android-19, so you just click `Open Android SDK Manager` and install "Android 4.4.2 (API 19)":

[image]

Then rebuild the project.

Comment: sorry,I forgot to say that I have install API 19,but it didn't work.

Comment: same error?if so,please paste your `build.gradle` and a screenshot of sdk versions you have installed.

Comment: oh,I find the error in the folder named as `.gradle`.I export gradle build files  from eclipse whose sdk location was `E:\android\android_sdk`.But my android studio sdk version is 23,so I changed Android studio sdk location as `E:\android\android_sdk_19\Android\Android\sdk`,Therefore,I met this problem when import the project into Android studio.My mother tongue isn't English,I can't express myself frequently.It's  my first question in stackoverflow,thank you for your help!lol.